# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method scanBarcode on channel flutter_barcode_scanner)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, error-handling

im trying to create an barcode scanner by:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner/install.

when i run my codes i get this error :

```
E/flutter ( 9248): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method scanBarcode on channel flutter_barcode_scanner)
E/flutter ( 9248): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
E/flutter ( 9248): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9248): #1      FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode (package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart:43:9)
E/flutter ( 9248): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9248): #2      _MyAppState.scanBarcodeNormal (package:styleupapp1/main.dart:46:24)
E/flutter ( 9248): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9248):
```

here's my codes:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _scanBarcode = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> startBarcodeScanStream() async {
    FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
        '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)!
        .listen((barcode) => print(barcode));
  }

  Future<void> scanQR() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
//barcode scanner flutter ant
    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }

  Future<void> scanBarcodeNormal() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }
//barcode scanner flutter ant
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Barcode Scanner')),
            body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Flex(
                      direction: Axis.vertical,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () => scanBarcodeNormal(),
                            child: const Text('Barcode scan')),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () => scanQR(),
                            child: const Text('QR scan')),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () => startBarcodeScanStream(),
                            child: const Text('Barcode scan stream')),
                        Text('Scan result : $_scanBarcode\n',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                      ]));
            })));
  }
}
```

has anyone experienced this error? i don't know what to do i tried different ways and packages but everyone gave me same error .
it's so important to me thanks for ur answers.

i asked once but no one answered. i really need to fix it.

Comment: Try to uninstall the app and run flutter clean and flutter pub get and run again

Comment: See https://github.com/AmolGangadhare/flutter_barcode_scanner/issues/249 it looks like other people had the same issue and were able to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify all reference `FlutterFragmentActivity` to `FlutterActivity`

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity
```

Or for Kotlin:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity()
```

More info here: [Plugin Api Migration](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration)

Comment: it is true but at first my project doesn't has **MainActivity.java** file. so i created that by run this command : `flutter create -a java .
`  and then the problem solved for me.

Comment: But what if you need the FlutterFragmentActivity()? I presume the package needs to be able to work with the MainActivity extending FlutterFragmentActivity

Comment: @NicParmee Ideally they should, but `FlutterActivity` comes as a part of v2 embedding, no one can blame library for not supporting the older plugins implementation. I thinks it's better to upgrade libraries still using v1 embedding to later one, or use older version of `flutter_barcode_scanner` (from changelog it seems v2 embedding was done in 1.0.0 version)

Answer (score 4):

1. Just stop your project
2. do "flutter clean"
3. then "flutter pub get"
4. Now, run your project again.

Hope that, it would work.

Eat Sleep Code Repeat.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this plugin with `FlutterFragmentActivity`, you can use this forked version which have removed all references to FragmentActivity

```
  flutter_barcode_scanner:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/itsAyyazdev/flutter_barcode_scanner.git
```