# MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method scanBarcode on channel flutter_barcode_scanner))

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode-scanner, flutter-getx

I am having a problem using the flutter_barcode_scanner

Scan Qr Code function in my controller looks like:

```
Future<void> scanqrcode() async {
    try {
      FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode('#AC22F', 'Cancel', false, ScanMode.QR)
          .then((value) {
        data = value;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      data = "Enable to read code";
    }
  }
```

The error says:

```
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method scanBarcode on channel flutter_barcode_scanner))
```

I tried to delete and add the flutter_barcode_scanner plugin again, also i tried to use flutter clean ,but noting works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method scanBarcode on channel flutter\_barcode\_scanner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562128/unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-s)

Comment: have you tried uninstall and install again your app after adding this library?

Comment: Sometime it's IDE problem you can try this below steps ||

Step 1: stop app & run flutter clean ||   
step 2: flutter pub get  ||
step 3: Again run app

Comment: @eamirho3ein No unfortunately, i have seen this question before i post mine.

Comment: @sumitanaiya yes, i tried but does not work.

Comment: @meetPatel I have mentioned that i tried to use flutter clean in my question

Comment: @MohammadYazbeck can you provide us screen shot where IDE is showing error ?

Comment: @MeetPatel Sure, (https://ibb.co/n3m7hNb)

Comment: @MohammadYazbeck i think this error is default from library it self so i think you should use another library for this

Comment: Just use this library if you want to scan QR or BARCODE. I've used it and it works: https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use [qr_code_scanner: ^0.5.2](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner/versions/0.5.2) library